# How can I render a razor view to a string without dependency on a controller context?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I render a razor view to a string without dependency on a controller context?

All the examples I have seen involve passing in a ControllerContext to my render helper class.  However, I don't want the dependency to the controller context as I want the rendered string to be generated inside a service.

Comment: You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/). And [another one](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/28/mvc-3-razor-view-engine-without-a-controller/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) seems to do exactly what you're looking for:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Comment: The problem with RazorEngine is that it does not currently support @Helper templates in the App_Code folder.

Comment: @William Doesn't support use of `@Html` helper either.